# Getting an error when running Laravel for the first time

Tags: laravel

Im running a new Laravel project and getting this error ,"**You're using the default database name laravel. This database does not exist.  Edit the .env file and use the correct database name in the DB_DATABASE key.**", But what's confusing is, its not the first time running a Laravel project,but I have never encountered such. Anyone to help?. Thanks in advance.

[image: Error]

Comment: Change your env file DB_DATABASE=DB_NAME_HERE
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Have there been an update of your system maybe? It seems to be a problem of php_openssl module and your installation of PHP.

Comment: Im using PHP from xaamp and I havent changed it, I actually have another Laravel Project running, but this new project is throwing the error. @jannej

Comment: @Md Juyel Rana, why should I change the DB_DATABASE to a "name" of a database that i haven't created, from my understanding, the project should run without ant errors before any edits, isn't that so?.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset the configuration in my **PhpStorm**, it was calling for **PHP 7.4** yet my installed version was **7.2**. Thanks to those who responded, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options;
If you are using [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead) then you need to configure your database connection as thus;

```
DB_DATABASE=name_of_database
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

If your environment is out of Homestead, then use the credentials you use when logging in to localhost/phpmyadmin
I hope it helps.